# Simple neural network refuses to overfit

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, keras

I wrote this super simple piece of code

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=d, activation='linear'))

model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10000, batch_size=n)
test_mse = model.evaluate(X_test, y_test)
print('test mse is {}'.format(test_mse))
```

X_train is an `n by d` numpy matrix and y is `n by 1` numpy matrix.
This is basically the simplest linear neural network you could think of. One layer, input dimension is d, and we output a number.

It simply refuses to overfit. Even after running an insane amount of iterations (10k as you can see), the training loss is at around 0.17.

I expect the loss to be zero. Why do I expect that? Because in my case, d is much greater than n. I have a lot more degrees of freedom. And as a further piece of evidence, when I actually solve `X_train @ w = y_train` using numpy.linalg.lstsq, the max value of `X_train @ w - y` is something like 10 to the -14.

So this system is definitely solvable. I expected to see zero loss or very close to zero loss, but I don't. Why?

Comment: Try: (1) adding more units into the dense layer; (2) training for more epochs.

Comment: what's the approx size of d and n?

Comment: I'm already training for 10k epochs. This seems excessive. By adding more units you mean the input dim? I can't do that. The input dim has to be the same as the dimension of the problem.

Comment: n = 1000, d = 5000. So in essence we are solving Ax = y where A is 1000 by 5000 and y is 1000 by 1. If A is full rank (and it is), there's infinitely many solutions. numpy.linalg.lstsq gives me a correct solution. Keras does not.

Comment: I would try SGD with a tuned learning rate (and possibly a LR schedule), because there are no guarantees that Adam will converge to the solution you want.